# Unable to increase open file limits in Linux

Tags: linux

I had an error message indicating that a process was unable to complete because the number of open files exceeded the limit. Checking the soft limit associated with my username

```
ulimit -Sn
```

gives a user soft limit 1024. I attempted to increase the soft limit associated with my username (I have root privilege) to 4096 following the instructions

https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/

i.e. in /etc/security/limits.conf I added the line

```
# <username> soft nofile 4096
```

When I exited and logged back in, the user limit was still 1024 (rebooting the server didn't reset it either).

Does the limits.conf file require a specific spacing (e.g. use of tabs vs. spaces, or a certain number of spaces between columns)? I can't think of anything else that may be wrong at this point.

Comment: Would this help? https://www.appservgrid.com/paw92/index.php/2019/03/26/how-to-increase-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux/

Comment: There are also `/etc/security/limits.d/` diretctory with files in it. `I added the line #` you added the line with `#` in front of it? If so, it's a comment.

Comment: The link provided https://www.appservgrid.com/paw92/index.php/2019/03/26/how-to-increase-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux/  gives the same instructions as the ones that I followed. Adding <username> soft nofiles 4096 doesn't change the file limit associated with username.

Comment: The directory /etc/security/limits.d is an empty directory on our server.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands for setting up soft limit and hard limit::

- Add below configuration in file /etc/security/limits.conf

- soft nofile 65536
- hard nofile 65536

- Add below configuration in /etc/sysctl.conf
  fs.file-max = 65536
- Add below configuraion in /etc/systemd/system.conf
  DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
- Add below configuraion in /etc/systemd/user.conf
  DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536

then restart the ubuntu/linux server
run below commands for checking soft limit and hard list
ulimit -Hn
ulimit -Sn

ps
cat /proc/PID/limits